# I don't know to find subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G=\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_5$

I don't know to find a subgroup.

Give me an example a subgroup of $G$ how to find that ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_3$ is a subgroup; $\mathbb Z_5$ is a subgroup. These are the only non-trivial subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Sure. $\{(0,0)\}$, for instance, is a subgroup.

Comment: Is $G$ cyclic ?

Comment: any a subgroup not identity ?

Comment: Use cyclic to find a subgroup ?

Comment: cyclic groups have certain subgroups

Comment: if i find a generator$(a)$ of $G$ then $<a>$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: No $<a>=G$ in your case.You have to find a generator $a$ of $G$ and then $<a^n>$ is a subgroup of $G$ for every positive $n| |G|$

Answer (score 3):

There are exactly 4 subgroups

1. $G$ itself is a subgroup of $G$
2. $\{(0,0)\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
3. $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\{0\}$ is a subgroup of $G$
4. $\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a subgroup of $G$.

There are no more subgroups of $G$.

How we find those? The group $G$ is a cyclic group because it is generated by $(1,1)$, hence every subgroup is a cyclic group as well. So you just take an element in $a\in G$ and you have that $\left<a\right>$ is a subgroup of $G$ (and every subgroup is of that form).

$G$ has 15 elements, but some of the elements define the same group (for example $\left<(1,0)\right> = \left<(2,0)\right> = \mathbb{Z}_3\times\{0\}$.
You can go over all elements and confirm that those 4 subgroups I mentioned before are the only subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $(3,5)=1$, $G$ is cuclic and $([1]_3,[1]_5)$ is a generator of $G$.

Now as I commented for every positive $n| |G|=15$ there exists a subgroup of $G$ the one that is generated by $([1]_3,[1]_5)^n$.So we have:

$1)$ for $n=1$:$<([1]_3,[1]_5)>=G$

$2)$ for $n=3$ :$<([0]_3,[3]_5)>=\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z_5}$

$3)$for $n=5$:$<([2]_3,[0]_5)>=\mathbb{Z_3}\times\{0\}$

$4)$for $n=15$:$<([0]_3,[0]_5)>=\{0,0\}$

Comment: that's a great answer why downvote?